# Running create-docusaurus from an electron app works in dev, but not in built app

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, docusaurus

I am using the `electron-react-boilerplate` to package my app and I am trying to execute a command to create a docusaurus project in my packaged app. `It works all good when runnning it in dev mode, but the packaged app would always throw an error.` I have tried both windows and linux versions to do this. Node version and npm version were the latest on both platforms.

### Error in the main process

```
*Error invoking remote method 'create-project': Error: Command failed: npx create-docusaurus@latest firstproject classic
file:///home/gergelybator/.npm/_npx/b61069f2430e9396/node_modules/create-docusaurus/bin/index.js:53
init(path.resolve(rootDir ?? '.'), siteName, template, options),
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)*
```

### Here is what i use to execute the command.

```js
// toPath is basically app.getPath("home") for linux and "document" for other platforms
async function createDocuProject(
    name: string,
    toPath: string
): Promise<string> {
    // ...other code...
    // create docusaurus project
    await execute(`npx create-docusaurus@latest ${name} classic`, toPath);
    // ...other code...
    return `${toPath}/${name}`;
}
```

#### execute() function used in the code above

```js
export async function execute(
    command: string,
    commandPath: string
): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(command, { cwd: commandPath }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            if (stdout) {
                resolve(stdout);
            }
            if (stderr) {
                resolve(stderr);
            }
            resolve("");
        });
    });
}
```

I have tried updating npm and node to the latest versions, however, it did not work on neither windows or linux.